# Socket Sessions For Persistent Connections

Tags: language-agnostic, session, sockets

I am developing a socket server where a client will be bound after being authenticated similar to SMPP. Is there support for cookies in this regard? How do you maintain a session for socket client that is "logged in"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unlike HTTP, sockets are inherently stateful, so maintaining state is a simple matter of associating data with the current socket connection. Cookies and such like are not necessary, because the server never loses its handle on the client.